# Java HashMap Error

Tags: java, hashmap

I have working on a problem where I am given a map (called `myMap`) where the keys are the names of authors, and the values are the names of the co-authors that the written has published articles with. I have to create a method that returns a String array containing the degrees of separation between a particular author, named ERDOS, and the other ones. I have written up the code below to do so; I am using a breadth first search.

```
   HashMap<String,Boolean> visitedMap= new HashMap<String,Boolean>();
   HashMap<String,Integer> distanceMap=new HashMap<String,Integer>();

     for(String name: myMap.keySet()){
         visitedMap.put(name, false);
     }
     for(String name:myMap.keySet()){
         distanceMap.put(name, -1);
     }
     distanceMap.put("ERDOS", 0);
     Queue<String> q= new LinkedList();
     q.add("ERDOS");
     visitedMap.put("ERDOS", true);


     int i=0;
     while(!q.isEmpty()){
         String a = q.remove();
         i=i+1;
         ArrayList<String> current= myMap.get(a);
         for(String z:current){
             System.out.println(current);
             System.out.println(visitedMap);
             if(visitedMap.get(current)==true){
                 q.add(z);
                 distanceMap.put(z, i);
                 visitedMap.put(z,true);
             }
             else{
                 break;
             }
         }
      }

      ArrayList<String> answer= new ArrayList<String>();
      for(String y:distanceMap.keySet()){
          answer.add("y"+" "+Integer.toString(distanceMap.get(y)));
      }
      String[] realAnswer= answer.toArray(new String[answer.size()]);
      Arrays.sort(realAnswer);
      return realAnswer;

}
```

However, I keep getting a null-pointer error when I call (visitedMap.get(current)==true). The two print statements before this line show that current is definitely present in visitedMap, and so I really don't understand the cause of this null-pointer exception. I would really appreciate any help.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`current` is an `ArrayList<String>`, while the keys in your map `visitedMap` are `String` objects. Therefore, `visitedMap.get(current)` will always return `null`.

You probably wanted to use: `visitedMap.get(z)` instead of `visitedMap.get(current)`.

Comment: Oh I can't believe I overlooked that. Thanks so much!